# Cannot upgrade from iOS 8.0.2 to iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad 2 and it currently has iOS 8.0.2, it says to install iOS 8.1 but when I click on update it brings up the agree or disagree the terms page as normal, and I click on agree and nothing happens, it just freezes and then times out!

What can I do about this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no iOS 8.2 - unless you are on about the beta, I suggest editing your question.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: I have 10gb of disk space avail

Comment: I always do mine on iTunes - sync, backup, download the update... *then* go for the install. 8.1 is installing right now. First thing you have to do for recent updates is unlock/login your phone when it starts, fingerprint or 1234 passcode

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this by making sure I was signed into iTunes, then agreeing to updated iTunes terms and conditions, then hard-resetting. I had not been signed in before, so I suspect that was holding things up.